# Changing a property stored as 'Data' in Applescript

Tags: applescript, imessage

I am working on a script that changes a person's Messages icon.

From the dictionary, Messages has a property called 'image', which contains the user's current icon.

This property is in the 'Data' format and so, when read, appears as a bunch of hexadecimal codes rather than, say, a file path. Here is the dictionary entry:

> image (TIFF picture): My image as it appears in all services.

My question is: how do I replace this property with another TIFF image of my choosing? Remember, the TIFF image I provide must be of in the format of 'data'.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
 set oldPic to newPic as «class rdat»
```

I don't know how to enter chevrons here, (`opt-shift v` and `opt-shift b` on my keyboard) , but the ´<<´ and ´>>´ are placeholders for chevrons.

I found the list of constants here: [WIK - AppleScript Classes & Constants](http://natural-innovations.com/as/classcodes.html)

Comment: Should be option-\ and option-shift-\ for chevrons on a Mac keyboard, but what does SO do with it? Let's see; I'll surround with ticks: `«»`

Comment: It really is locale dependent where the keys goes. Thanks for the tip about ticks, however, I haven't been able to make it work yet. :/ Did you mean forward or backward ticks, around regular less than and greater than pairs?

Comment: When writing a comment (like this), the 'help' link/button will show you formatting techniques, like using back-ticks (`) to format code. I did this to isolate the chevrons. And yeah, how damned US-centric of me regarding the keyboard. I apologize!

Comment: I realized I could use ctrl-q, for quote, and then enter the keys. (I have a heavily modded cocoa text system. :)